# I want to hide/show my SVG elements, while using it in anguarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

Can anybody suggest me a JS function which makes this SVG visible, as it's was working perfect while without angular JS.

```
<div class="app" ng-app ng-style="disableCircle">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlSizing">
        <label id="rad" style="visibility: hidden">Radius: <input ng-model="rad" type="number" placeholder="How about 300?"></label>
        <div id="circle" style="height: 800; width: 500; position:absolute; left: 100px;top: 100px;">
            <svg width="500" height="500" visibility="visible" onclick="cInput()" >
                <circle id="circle1" cx="150" cy="150" ng-attr-r="{{rad}}" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="grey" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Circle" onclick="circleDraw()">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JS to hide the element retrieved by id or traversing the DOM.

```
svgElement.style.display = "none";
```

or

```
svgElement.style.opacity = 0;
```

For more information on how to interact with the SVG using JS you can check this article [Interfacing with SVG](http://tumba.solutions/blog/svg)